# CURL: How to input type="submit"

Tags: linux, curl

I'm having a hard time understanding how to submit something using curl. I have already logged in successfully using this code:

```
curl $HOST -s -L -b $COOKIE -c $COOKIE -d "login=submit&login_name=$USER&login_password=$PASS" > /dev/null
<input name="login" type="hidden" id="login" value="submit" />
```

but when I try something similar with another page it doesn't work, it's driving me nuts:

```
curl $RSS -s -L -b $COOKIE -c $COOKIE -F "submitrssauto=doit"  -o rss

<form  name="submitrss" action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="submitrssauto" id="submitrssauto" value="doit" class="buttons">
    <input type=hidden name="allow_main" value="1">
    <input type=hidden name="allow_rating" value="1">
    <input type=hidden name="allow_comm" value="1">
    <input type=hidden name="lastdate" value="1345109704">
    <input type=hidden name="id" value="4">
    <input type="hidden" name="user_hash" value="e6bf03ffeb6865eadb62eb9d7d99c88e" />
    <input type=hidden name="text_type" value="1">
</forum>
```

php code:

```
                echo <<<HTML

    <br />&nbsp;&nbsp;
<form  name="submitrss" action="" method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="submitrssauto" id="submitrssauto" value="doit" class="buttons">
        <input type=hidden name="allow_main" value="{$rss['allow_main']}">
        <input type=hidden name="allow_rating" value="{$rss['allow_rating']}">
        <input type=hidden name="allow_comm" value="{$rss['allow_comm']}">
        <input type=hidden name="lastdate" value="{$xml->lastdate}">
        <input type=hidden name="id" value="{$id}">
        <input type="hidden" name="user_hash" value="$dle_login_hash" />
        <input type=hidden name="text_type" value="{$rss['text_type']}">
</forum>
HTML;
```

this is what I've tried so far:

```
   curl $RSS -s -L -b $COOKIE -c $COOKIE -F "submitrssauto=doit"  -o rss
    curl $RSS -s -L -b $COOKIE -c $COOKIE -d "submitrssauto=doit"  -o rss
    curl $RSS -s -L -b $COOKIE -c $COOKIE -o rss -d "submitrssauto=doit&allow_main=1&allow_rating=1&allow_comm=1&lastdate=1345109704‌​&id=4&user_hash=e6bf03ffeb6865eadb62eb9d7d99c88e&text_type=1"
```

Comment: That `-d` parameter, that has the variables from a form in it, formatted in the convention for HTTP.  You need to translate your form to that.

Comment: eg. `curl $RSS -s -L -b $COOKIE -c $COOKIE -o rss -d "submitrssauto=doit&allow_main=1&allow_rating=1&allow_comm=1&lastdate=1345109704&id=4&user_hash=e6bf03ffeb6865eadb62eb9d7d99c88e&text_type=1"`

Comment: Or you can use `-F` per variable.

Comment: didn't work... not with -F and not with -d

Comment: Well, that's how you post data to a URL with cURL - how exactly is it not working?

Comment: i believe you, seams like i missing something. there's one button on the page "doit" and it doesn't get "submitted" with curl.

Comment: Did you try running the command given by @Orbling? The second command in your question only has one of the parameters from the form you need to submit. If you update the OP with all that you've tried, it would help us understand better.

Comment: yes I've tried. because all of the other parameters generated automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Developer Tools of Chrome or Firebug of Firefox to trace the HTTP communication process.That may help you.

The data posted may be processed by like js scripts,so you may ignore sth if you only use the source of web pages.

Comment: In the "net" tab,you can see the final data after processed.